# Java concurrent modification exception when removing items from list

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.util.ConcurrentModificationException on ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145135/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-on-arraylist)

I am trying to remove items from a list inside a thread. I am getting the  `ConcurrentModificationException`. I read from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090398/java-concurrent-modification-exception) that it's related to removing items from list. I am putting the sample code below. How can I do this properly without this exception in my case.

```
try 
{
    for(Game game:appDeleg.getGlobalGames().getGames())
    {
        if(game.getOwner().getId().equals(params[0]))
        {
            synchronized (appDeleg.getGlobalGames().getGames())
            {
                appDeleg.getGlobalGames().getGames().remove(game);
            }
        }

    }
}

catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "noconnection";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use Iterator:

```
Iterator<Game> i = appDeleg.getGlobalGames().getGames().iterator();

Game game;
while(i.hasNext()) {
    game = i.next();
    if(game.getOwner().getId().equals(params[0]))
          i.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to use `Iterator<Game> i=appDeleg.getGlobalGames().getGames().iterator();` to get the iterator

Comment: right, was in a rush to get a vote :)

Answer (score 2):

The enhanced for loop uses an iterator. The iterator can throw an exception if something modifies the collection as it is iterating through it.

In your case you are removing the item through the collection not through the iterator.

Try use a standard for loop and not using the implied iterator.
Assuming your collection is an array list.

```
ArrayList games = appDeleg.getGlobalGames().getGames();
for(int i=0;i<games.size();i++){
      Game game = games.get(i);
      if(game.getOwner().getId().equals(params[0])){
       games.remove(i);

      }
}
```

Comment: it worked for me while i was using ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Collect the to be removed items in a new list and remove them after you looped through the original list.

Comment: Or remove items from iterator itself not collection.

Answer (score 1):

synchornized keyword will not protect you here. 
You can reach this exception event from single-threaded appication (yes - you may claim the name of the exception is misleading). 
This should be done using iterator to iterate over the list, 
(Which will allow you to call remove when you reach the value you want to remove), 
or by collecting the elements you want to remove to a separate list, and then run the removeAll method on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not remove item of a list while iterating, it throws `ConcurrentModificationException`

> If the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created,
>   in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator 
>   will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent 
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, 
>   non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

docs -> [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

you should you `Iterator` for removing item from list.